# How to recover MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm not able to run MongoDB after shutdown, is there a way to recover MongoDB from a situation like this:

```
$sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --repair

2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=32710 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=node888-parse.hostname888.com
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.1
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-03-15T11:40:05.236+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo" } }
2017-03-15T11:40:05.256+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-03-15T11:40:05.256+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected WT journal files.  Running recovery from last checkpoint.
2017-03-15T11:40:05.256+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] journal to nojournal transition config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-03-15T11:40:05.282+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (22) [1489578005:281966][32710:0x7f8ff0669dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: live.avail: merge range 16384-28672 overlaps with existing range 20480-28672: Invalid argument
2017-03-15T11:40:05.282+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (-31804) [1489578005:282052][32710:0x7f8ff0669dc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2017-03-15T11:40:05.282+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558
2017-03-15T11:40:05.282+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure


2017-03-15T11:40:05.313+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x12eaa52 0x12e9bb9 0x12ea3c2 0x7f8feefca100 0x7f8feec2e5f7 0x7f8feec2fce8 0x12754b2 0x1074443 0x1a299cc 0x1a29b6d 0x1a29f54 0x19659dd 0x1966b64 0x1966db3 0x1963ec7 0x1967b7e 0x1983c58 0x19b53d0 0x1a287cb 0x1a28cc6 0x19f3353 0x19b2323 0x105a94e 0x1057c90 0xf85018 0x9914f1 0x94cd79 0x7f8feec1ab15 0x98f08d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"EEAA52"},{"b":"400000","o":"EE9BB9"},{"b":"400000","o":"EEA3C2"},{"b":"7F8FEEFBB000","o":"F100"},{"b":"7F8FEEBF9000","o":"355F7"},{"b":"7F8FEEBF9000","o":"36CE8"},{"b":"400000","o":"E754B2"},{"b":"400000","o":"C74443"},{"b":"400000","o":"16299CC"},{"b":"400000","o":"1629B6D"},{"b":"400000","o":"1629F54"},{"b":"400000","o":"15659DD"},{"b":"400000","o":"1566B64"},{"b":"400000","o":"1566DB3"},{"b":"400000","o":"1563EC7"},{"b":"400000","o":"1567B7E"},{"b":"400000","o":"1583C58"},{"b":"400000","o":"15B53D0"},{"b":"400000","o":"16287CB"},{"b":"400000","o":"1628CC6"},{"b":"400000","o":"15F3353"},{"b":"400000","o":"15B2323"},{"b":"400000","o":"C5A94E"},{"b":"400000","o":"C57C90"},{"b":"400000","o":"B85018"},{"b":"400000","o":"5914F1"},{"b":"400000","o":"54CD79"},{"b":"7F8FEEBF9000","o":"21B15"},{"b":"400000","o":"58F08D"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.1", "gitVersion" : "a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "2.6.32-042stab120.19", "version" : "#1 SMP Mon Feb 20 20:05:53 MSK 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "82DE04175D9E4EDD5FB2C7106D67B02C808D491C" }, { "b" : "7FFE970DE000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D60784814810B7259AE2B6DCF6DCBD9A04442AF7" }, { "b" : "7F8FF01EB000", "path" : "/lib64/libssl.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7A36D093BFFC7FDC70BCB163A06077F1B059ABD4" }, { "b" : "7F8FEFE03000", "path" : "/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "94BE6FDE7025B1ED23BE379A30C1E0E67BCF61B1" }, { "b" : "7F8FEFBFB000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1D2AD4EAA62BAD560685A4B8DCCC8D9AA95E22CE" }, { "b" : "7F8FEF9F7000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "091060A163E7EDA25572F3B1BAF2E8F80209C00E" }, { "b" : "7F8FEF6EF000", "path" : "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8941888BF8EE9CED585599BE5397A385FC1C73CE" }, { "b" : "7F8FEF3ED000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6DADD94D2A0885D50D09C465EA1970F23FB4629D" }, { "b" : "7F8FEF1D7000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6AA1DCC4DE7F1836344949857FC2017278631FFD" }, { "b" : "7F8FEEFBB000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DF6CCEE00C9F4C983A9464E43D17CC3311B51A8F" }, { "b" : "7F8FEEBF9000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "53C0918C85FA9CC08D2B57E76467631AB07554AE" }, { "b" : "7F8FF0458000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F9AF7BA309F063D3BF9657A21436B4DCAC03CF07" }, { "b" : "7F8FEE9AD000", "path" : "/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D46A230FFF4A7B808B3CFC213D31FCAC542FB504" }, { "b" : "7F8FEE6C8000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6D6136A0E795420B05854DEF13A10C226FE9CCB2" }, { "b" : "7F8FEE4C4000", "path" : "/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4FAF527D49C0C2EBB8108D72B5316ADA49361F65" }, { "b" : "7F8FEE292000", "path" : "/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AA97A848DD7C9E57B06EC913E10D420AEBBCE027" }, { "b" : "7F8FEE07C000", "path" : "/lib64/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1982C8CDAE90F898D1AD26DC07E807333B4789D0" }, { "b" : "7F8FEDE6D000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AEF6C3D3C5152F339942041519A106FC055DAF71" }, { "b" : "7F8FEDC69000", "path" : "/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2E01D5AC08C1280D013AAB96B292AC58BC30A263" }, { "b" : "7F8FEDA4F000", "path" : "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D587388512371B074E16632C01840EA00F0B1175" }, { "b" : "7F8FED82A000", "path" : "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "82FF6B18E1E42825CC2D060F969479AD4AF2F62C" }, { "b" : "7F8FED5C9000", "path" : "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AE64AA461A26E01F60408013D361749D56DD0AE1" }, { "b" : "7F8FED3A4000", "path" : "/lib64/liblzma.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "98131C9354279ABD39FD80D4BE5B3EC5678BD9E0" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x12eaa52]
 mongod(+0xEE9BB9) [0x12e9bb9]
 mongod(+0xEEA3C2) [0x12ea3c2]
 libpthread.so.0(+0xF100) [0x7f8feefca100]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7f8feec2e5f7]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f8feec2fce8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x82) [0x12754b2]
 mongod(+0xC74443) [0x1074443]
 mongod(__wt_eventv+0x40C) [0x1a299cc]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x8D) [0x1a29b6d]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x24) [0x1a29f54]
 mongod(+0x15659DD) [0x19659dd]
 mongod(__wt_block_extlist_read+0x394) [0x1966b64]
 mongod(__wt_block_extlist_read_avail+0x33) [0x1966db3]
 mongod(__wt_block_checkpoint_load+0x3B7) [0x1963ec7]
 mongod(+0x1567B7E) [0x1967b7e]
 mongod(__wt_btree_open+0xC68) [0x1983c58]
 mongod(__wt_conn_btree_open+0x140) [0x19b53d0]
 mongod(__wt_session_get_btree+0xEB) [0x1a287cb]
 mongod(__wt_session_get_btree+0x5E6) [0x1a28cc6]
 mongod(__wt_metadata_open+0x33) [0x19f3353]
 mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x15E3) [0x19b2323]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKSsS2_S2_mbbb+0x45E) [0x105a94e]
 mongod(+0xC57C90) [0x1057c90]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x588) [0xf85018]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x321) [0x9914f1]
 mongod(main+0x149) [0x94cd79]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF5) [0x7f8feec1ab15]
 mongod(+0x58F08D) [0x98f08d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I have same issue.

Comment: Apparently was not able to fix...